# vsftpd and chroot: can i share the chroot folder between two users?

Tags: ftp, chroot, vsftpd, ftps

I have a vsftpd installation with chroot enabled and root access disabled.
Everything work flawlessy, but I need to accomplish this.

When user1 log into ftps, it log in /home/user1. Same for user2, user3 and so on.
I want to have user1_viewer which log into ftps but chrooted in /home/user1 (and NOT /home/user1_viewer) automatically with read only privileges.

Is this possible?

Workarounds accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the home folder for `user1_viewer` to `/home/user1`.

```
usermod -d /home/user1 user1_viewer
```

So long as you have the permissions set right and ownership of the file is on `user1` and not `user1_viewer` (which should already be set) you don't have to worry about `user1_viewer` modifying anything in the folder.

> Yay! It worked! Needs to be executable... So the right answer, mixing your answers and tips, is: `usermod -d /home/user1 user1_viewer` and then `setfacl -R -m u:user1_viewer:rx /home/user1` Thanks a lot guys! malan maybe u can update your answer including @DanilaLadner tip!

--Per Asker

Comment: that should work since each user's jail is derived from their home directory string in /etc/passwd.

Comment: uhm output here is:
"OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/user1" (WinSCP)
With ownership set to user1 as you said
So it reads user2's home correctly but cannot CD there...

Comment: Did you sudo? I forgot to include that in the command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259791/how-to-change-the-home-directory-of-the-currently-logged-in-user

Comment: Yes I sudo (i'm root), but the command is correctly executed...is the ftp client that give me that output
The home is correctly changed but with ftp i can't connect due to that output

Comment: you would need to setup ACLS for user1_viewer to have read access of home dir of user1

Comment: Why couldn't you just make the permissions for the folder 755? As long as other is set to read and execute it shouldn't be a problem. Wyatt: what directory is showing when you winscp in as user2?

Comment: Because you will break ssh with 755 on home directory

Comment: With permission 755 same error shows up...  when i winscp in as user2, after doing usermod as shown by you, it appears  "OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/user1" 
@DanilaLadner i did setfacl -m u:user2:r /home/user1 but same error appears

Comment: also needs to be executable, also check selinux please.

Comment: Yay! It worked! Needs to be executable...
So the right answer, mixing your answers and tips, is:
"usermod -d /home/user1 user1_viewer" and then
"setfacl -R -m u:user1_viewer:rx /home/user1"

Thanks a lot guys! malan maybe u can update your answer including @DanilaLadner tip!

Comment: This is starting to get over my head, Danila seems to know what he's talking about and I'd rely on him now, but this might help: https://nurikabe.blog/2009/06/15/defeating-vsftp-error-500-oops-cannot-change-directorysomedirectory/ It references SELinux being the cause of that problem, just like Danila says.

Comment: Read carefully my last comment, the problem was in the ACLS, and now it's solved and it's working as a charm ^_^ Thanks to you both!